# AS3: Change values of an object

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, undefined

I'm working with **QuickBox2D**.

I dropped a ball using the following statement.

```
            gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(2), radius:0.15, density:1, restitution:0.7, friction:0, skin:ball, scaleSkin:false, angularDamping:20});
```

During an if statement I want to change two values inside the Object:

```
                gameBall({friction:1,restitution:0});
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Call to a possibly undefined method gameBall.
```

**Complete Code:**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(width = 300, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

public class LuckyHitBeta extends MovieClip {

    public var sim:QuickBox2D;
    var winBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox2:QuickObject;
    var gameBall:QuickObject;
    var simContacts:QuickContacts;
    var isFiring:Boolean=false;
    var ballIcon:ballIcon_mc;



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function LuckyHitBeta()
    {   
        liveIcon();
        sim = new QuickBox2D(this);
        simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
        simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
        //Important Collisions;

        winBox = sim.addBox({x:2,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        looseBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        looseBox2 = sim.addBox({x:8,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        //Collisions
        sim.addBox({x:3.5,y:560/30, width:72/30, height:13/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:6.5,y:560/30, width:72/30, height:13/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:0/30,y:300/30, width:600/30, height:28/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:300/30,y:300/30, width:600/30, height:28/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});



        // make obstacles 
        for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/28); i++){ 
        //End
             sim.addCircle({x:1.2 + i * 0.8, y:16, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:0.6 + i * 0.8, y:15, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
        }

        for (var o:int = 0; o<(stage.stageWidth/55); o++){  
        //Middle

              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:14, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:13, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:12, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:11, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:10, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
        }

        for (var u:int = 0; u<(stage.stageWidth/45); u++){    
        //Start
             sim.addCircle({x:0.8 + u * 1.3, y:09, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:1.55 + u * 1.3, y:08, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:0.8 + u * 1.3, y:07, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:1.55 + u * 1.3, y:06, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});

        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        sim.start();



    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
     */
     private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
     {  
        if (! isFiring){
            gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(2), radius:0.15, density:1, restitution:0.7, friction:0, skin:ball, scaleSkin:false, angularDamping:20});
            isFiring=true;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(2);

        }  
     }

    private function liveIcon():void {
        ballIcon=new ballIcon_mc();
        addChild(ballIcon);
        ballIcon.y=30;
    }        

     private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void
     {          
        ballIcon.x=mouseX;
        if (gameBall && gameBall.body.IsSleeping())
            {
                gameBall.destroy();
                gameBall = null;
                isFiring=false;
                ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);
            }  
    }

    private function contactListener(e:Event)
    {
        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
            isFiring=false;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);
        }

        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(looseBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Loose.
            trace ('You loose!');
            gameBall({friction:1,restitution:0});
            isFiring=false;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

In your code, `gameBall` is a variable referring to the `QuickObject` created by the `addCircle` method. But, in the line,

```
gameBall({friction:1,restitution:0});
```

you use `gameBall` as a function, when it is an object. The solution is

```
gameBall.params.friction = 1.0;
gameBall.params.restitution = 0.0;
```

Note that you don't want to do,

```
gameBall.params = { friction: 1.0, restitution: 0.0 };
```

because it would overwrite all of your other parameters.

The docs for `QuickObject` are [here](http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/docs/html/index.html).

Comment: To make sure the changes occurred, i placed `density = 0;` as soon as the ball makes contact with the ground. But the ball keeps bouncing. No signs of change!

Answer (score 1):

`gameBall` is some `Object`, yet you are trying to use it as a `function` (mind the brackets `( )`). Usually you access properties of objects in such notation:

`object.property = value;`

Although I'm not sure if `QuickBox2D` allows you to change those properties after object initialization. It's been a while since I worked with `Box2D`.